# Unity UNet: как заставить клиент получать полную информацию о всех игровых объектах на сервере?

Tags: сервер, unity3d, разработка-игр, сеть

Есть работающий игровой сервер на 300+ NetworkBehaviour, где часть из них без NetworkTransform (деревья, кусты, камни) и с NetworkTransform (всякие расходники, которые "по физике" могут падать на землю).
Если игрок заходит в игру не на старте сервера (когда порциями выдаётся игроку созданный мир, а уже как initial full state), клиент выборочно не создает некоторые из объектов мира (включая сам префаб игрока). После этого в консоли начинается спам, о том что не найден объект для синхронизации:

> "Did not find target for sync message for %NUMBER%".

А теперь два вопроса:

1. Могу ли я изменить дефолтный канал для спауна геймобъектов с `Channels.DefaultReliable` на `ReliableFragmented`?
2. Могу ли я научить HLAPI разрезать большой объем исходящего трафика на несколько частей (по аналогии с Fragmented?)

Comment: Вы на русскоязычном стековерфлоу. Задавайте вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: Каюсь, исправился

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле всё оказалось куда проще. Разобрал managed-код библиотеки UnityEngine.Networking через ILSpy и ответ нашелся сам. В данном случае когда сервер намеревается отправлять пакеты данных, он складывает их очередь. Дефолтный максимальный размер этой очереди равен 128. Чтоб его изменить требуется до старта сервера изменить значение: 
    `NetworkManager.connectionConfig.MaxSentMessageQueueSize` на 256 или больше, в зависимости от нужд.

UPD1: так же необходимо учитывать, что в NetworkManager в списке Channels должно быть так или аналогично:

- 0 канал = любой надежный (reliable), т.к. именно в этом канала будет
  происходить спаун геймобъектов
- 1 канал = любой ненадежный (unreliable), т.к. в этом канале будет
  отсылаться вся информация о передвижении (из компоненты
  NetworkTransform и аналогичных)